# Why the regular expression is not allowing alphabets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this to restrict user from inputting numbers. I want him to only input alphabets like a,b,c,d,e etc

but it works oppositely.

```
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[A-Za-z]*/, '');" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" required>
```

Comment: Because you're replacing every span of alphanumeric characters with an empty string? Put `^` as the first character after the opening square bracket if you want to invert the range.

Comment: can you fix it because i tried everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `/[0-9]/, ''`

```html
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[0-9]/, '');" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" required>
```

Comment: So get rid of numbers but allow spaces and punctuation?

Comment: while mine doesn't

Comment: You need to check when key up to block copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```js
this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]*/, '')
```

?

Comment: yes, it allows both... i want only alphabets not numeric. It does both

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using HTML5's [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#pattern) attribute instead, and mark invalid fields using the corresponding [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) CSS modifier.

The difference is that the user may input numbers but won't be able to submit the form. This way he/she knows what's wrong and can fix his/her mistake.

Demo:

```css
input:invalid {border: 2px solid red;}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" pattern="[^\d]+" required>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can also add a custom validation message:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-invalid]').forEach(function (input) {
    input.addEventListener('invalid', function () { 
      input.setCustomValidity(input.dataset.invalid); 
    });
    input.addEventListener('input', function () {
      input.setCustomValidity(''); 
    })
  });
});
```

```css
input:invalid {border: 2px solid red;}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" pattern="[^\d]+" data-invalid="Your name cannot contain numbers!" required>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```